# Database control or control datas after I pull them out

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to ask which approach is better/faster. Should I pull out the data's from database and then proccess them with a programming language, or should I just pull out the data I want by doing the controls inside SQL Query??(which means the design of database will be more complicated). I think doing the controls in programming language is slower + i would need to withdraw A lot data, in huge databases it would be nonsense. In my case I want to design a database that has in store strings of file paths for images...

Comment: What do you mean with *controls*?

Comment: checking, parsing

Comment: Usually it is better to check *constraints* at the database level. Since databases are optimized to check constraints, and furthermore the amount of data that is *transfered* will be lower and therefore less computational effort will invested. Unless of course the constraint is *that complicated* that it would take considerable amount of time.

Comment: by saying constraints you mean what it is called "indexes" of database??

Comment: "indexes" are not "constraints". Those are really two different things, though we do make use of indexes to enforce some constraints. Use database features for things the database is good at. Use client code to handle things the database doesn't do well. Use a divide and conquer approach, use both. If we approach the problem as "do everything in the database" or "do everything in the client", performance is going to suffer.

Comment: definitely a "depends" question!  I have done one, the other, or a combination of both depending on the specific requirements.  There isn't a single one-size-fits all answer for this i'm afraid, so more details would be required for us to be more specific.

Comment: The scenario is I have a database with file paths for images, The user is gonna type some keywords and I need to check those keywords to get the correct filepath and then doing some further checkings to go to the correct subfolders otherwise im in the correct filepath but there is no specific subfolder so I would show some random imgs of this folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about balance.

Selecting huge amounts of data and transferring them back to your client code will take time, and load your network and your database.

If the processing you want to do on the data can be done inside the database, then this will of course be a lot faster.

If, however, said processing involves complex application code that takes a long time to run, it can be an option.

For example, let's say you grab 10000 rows from your database, and it takes a second. If your program does something interesting with them, and it takes 10 minutes, then the time to bring in the data is well amortized. If, on the other hand, all you do is set x=x+1, then really.... no.